# How to MPI_Gatherv columns from processor, where each process may send different number of columns

Tags: c, mpi

Say 2 processes are participating. Process 0 (rank 0) has

```
A = { a d
      b e
      c f
    }
```

and process 1 (rank 1) has

```
A = { g
      h
      i
    }
```

I want both processors to send these columns to rank 0 so that rank 0 will have the following in say another 2D-array.

```
B = { a d g
      b e h
      c f i
    }
```

I create a new column data type for the MPI_Gatherv and am trying the following code, which is getting me no where.

My specific questions are:

1. How should I approach this
2. What should be the send_type and recv_type.
3. How should displacements be specified ( should they be in term of the new data type or MPI_CHAR)

Thanks.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int numprocs, my_rank;
   long int i, j;
   MPI_Status status;
   char **A;
   char **B;
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

  if(my_rank == 0)
  {
    A = (char **)calloc((3), sizeof(char *));
    B = (char **)calloc((3), sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
       A[i] = (char *)calloc(2, sizeof(char));
       B[i] = (char *)calloc(3, sizeof(char));
    }

    A[0][0] = 'a';
    A[1][0] = 'b';
    A[2][0] = 'c';
    A[0][1] = 'd';
    A[1][1] = 'e';
    A[2][1] = 'f';
  }
  else
  {
    A = (char **)calloc((3), sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
       A[i] = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    }
    A[0][0] = 'g';
    A[1][0] = 'h';
    A[2][0] = 'i';

  }
  MPI_Datatype b_col_type;
  MPI_Type_vector(3, 1, 1, MPI_CHAR, &b_col_type);
  MPI_Type_commit(&b_col_type);
  int displs[2] = {0, 2};
  int recvcounts[2] = {2, 1};
  MPI_Gatherv(&A[0][0], recvcounts[my_rank], b_col_type, &B[0][0], recvcounts, displs,    b_col_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if(my_rank == 0)
  {
    for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
      for(j=0; j<3; ++j)
        printf("%c ", B[i][j]);
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it's getting you nowhere"? What's the exact problem?

Comment: So if I try to run the above code the stuff that gets in to B is only

$ mpirun -np 2 try_gather
a d


So only the rank 0 is able to send its 2 elements. I tried tweaking with the values of displs and recvcounts however i couldn't get what I am aiming for. The current code at least put 2 characters in the right place.
I give up on trying to format the code in the comments section. Basically 'a' and 'd' go to the right place. Rest all are blanks in array B.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So first off - and this comes up with MPI and C arrays all the time - you can't really do the standard C two dimensional array thing.   Let's look at this:

```
A = (char **)calloc((3), sizeof(char *));
for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
{
   A[i] = (char *)calloc(2, sizeof(char));
}
```

This will definately allocate a 3x2 array of characters, but you have no idea how the resulting data is laid out in memory.   In particular, there's no guarantee at *all* that `A[1][0]` immediately follows `A[0][1]`.   That makes it very difficult to create MPI datatypes which span the data structure!   You need to allocate 3x2 contiguous bytes, and then make the array point into it:

```
char **charalloc2d(int n, int m) {
    char *data = (char *)calloc(n*m,sizeof(char));
    char **array = (char **)calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[i*m]);

    return array;
}

void charfree2d(char **array) {
    free(array[0]);
    free(array);
    return;
}

/* ... */
nrows = 3;
ncols = 2;
A = charalloc2d(nrows,ncols);
```

Now we know something about the layout of the array, and can depend on that to build datatypes.

You're on the right track with the data types --

```
MPI_Datatype b_col_type;
MPI_Type_vector(3, 1, 1, MPI_CHAR, &b_col_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&b_col_type);
```

the signature of MPI_Type_vector is  (count,  blocklen,  stride, old_type,  *newtype).
We want nrows characters, that come in blocks of 1; but they're spaced ncols apart; so that's the stride.

Note that this is really the column type of the `A` array, rather than `B`; the type will depend on the number of columns in the array.  So each process is using a different sendtype, which is fine.

```
MPI_Datatype a_col_type;
MPI_Type_vector(nrows, 1, ncols, MPI_CHAR, &a_col_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&a_col_type);
```

The final step is the `MPI_Gatherv`, and here you have to be a little cute.   The trick is, we want to send (and receive) multiple of these things at a time - that is, several consecutive ones.   But we need the next column not to be nrows*ncols chars away, but just one char away.   Luckily, we can do that by setting the upper bound of the data structure to be just one character away from the lower bound, so that the next element does start in the right place.   This is allowed by [the standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report.pdf), and in fact one of their examples in section 4.1.4 there hinges on it.

To do that, we create a resized type that ends just one byte after it starts:

```
MPI_Type_create_resized(a_col_type, 0, 1*sizeof(char), &new_a_col_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&new_a_col_type);
```

and similarly for `B`; and now we can send and recieve multiples of these as one would expect.   So the following works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

char **charalloc2d(int n, int m) {
    char *data = (char *)calloc(n*m,sizeof(char));
    char **array = (char **)calloc(n, sizeof(char *));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[i*m]);

    return array;
}

void charfree2d(char **array) {
    free(array[0]);
    free(array);
    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numprocs, my_rank;
    int nrows, ncols, totncols;
    long int i, j;
    char **A;
    char **B;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    if(my_rank == 0)
    {
        nrows=3;
        ncols=2;
        totncols = 3;

        A = charalloc2d(nrows, ncols);
        B = charalloc2d(nrows, totncols);

        A[0][0] = 'a';
        A[1][0] = 'b';
        A[2][0] = 'c';
        A[0][1] = 'd';
        A[1][1] = 'e';
        A[2][1] = 'f';
    }
    else
    {
        nrows = 3;
        ncols = 1;
        A = charalloc2d(nrows, ncols);
        B = charalloc2d(1,1); /* just so gatherv survives */
        A[0][0] = 'g';
        A[1][0] = 'h';
        A[2][0] = 'i';

    }
    MPI_Datatype a_col_type, new_a_col_type;
    MPI_Type_vector(nrows, 1, ncols, MPI_CHAR, &a_col_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&a_col_type);

    /* make the type have extent 1 character -- now the next
     * column starts in the next character of the array 
     */
    MPI_Type_create_resized(a_col_type, 0, 1*sizeof(char), &new_a_col_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&new_a_col_type);

    MPI_Datatype b_col_type, new_b_col_type;
    if (my_rank == 0) {
        MPI_Type_vector(nrows, 1, totncols, MPI_CHAR, &b_col_type);
        MPI_Type_commit(&b_col_type);

        /* similarly "resize" b columns */
        MPI_Type_create_resized(b_col_type, 0, 1*sizeof(char), &new_b_col_type);
        MPI_Type_commit(&new_b_col_type);
    }

    int displs[2] = {0, 2};
    int recvcounts[2] = {2, 1};
    MPI_Gatherv(A[0], recvcounts[my_rank], new_a_col_type,
                B[0], recvcounts, displs, new_b_col_type,
                0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if(my_rank == 0)
    {
        for(i=0; i<3; ++i)
        {
            for(j=0; j<3; ++j)
                printf("%c ", B[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. I realized later that my arrays were not contiguous in memory. So for now I plan to use a Send/Recv combination with different MPI_Datatype for each process and not use MPI_Gatherv. I guess that is what you are alluding to too?

Comment: Store the matrix on column-major order. That way, a single column will be a simple `MPI_Contiguous` datatype, and you can easily send/receive them with `Gatherv()` (2 columns from process 0 with displacement 0, and 1 column from process 1 with displacement 2). This fits the way you decompose your data better anyway.

Comment: @suszterpatt I do not want to store in column major format because the different processors compute and store data into their `A[][]` arrays in row major order and the arrays in reality are quite large, hence the writes will possibly cause a lot of memory thrashing.

Comment: @Jonathan, in the example in the question, in case rank 1 has the 2 columns instead of one `A = { g h i j k l }` Then using the `MPI_Type_vector(3, 1, 2, MPI_CHAR, &a_col_type)` I cannot `MPI_Send` both the columns to rank 0 if I call `MPI_Send` like this `MPI_Send(&A[0][0], 2, a_col_type, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD)`. Only the first column and last charater `l` and up being sent. I can see why, after `i` is sent the next element in memory is `l`. It shouldn't be so hard to send a couple of columns!

Comment: You know, it might be possible to use mpi_type_create_resized to force the "size" of the structure to be just one character, so the next one would come immediately afterwards... I doubt that's valid, though.

Comment: Ah hah!  That was the trick.   Answer is updated; it works now.

Comment: Thanks! Before I was using a rather expensive and clumsy method where I first copied the elements in a 1D array and then copied them again into the right places in the 2D array.