# MPI_Scatter - sending columns of 2D array

Tags: c, mpi

I want to send 2D array's columns, each to separate process. I have now one whole 2d array and I am stuck with MPI_Scatter. How to send whole columns as a field?

Thanks

**edit:**

I have array - float a[100][101]

and I have tried to send array by:

```
float send;
MPI_Scatter ((void *)a, n, MPI_FLOAT,(void *)&send  , 1, MPI_INT,0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Edit2:

I have made new type_vector:

```
               MPI_Datatype newtype;

               MPI_Type_vector(n,       /* # column elements */
                   1,           /* 1 column only */
                   n+1,         /* skip n+1 elements */
                   MPI_FLOAT,       /* elements are float */
                   &newtype);       /* MPI derived datatype */

               MPI_Type_commit(&newtype);
```

and now Iam trying to send it to my other processes. Matrix is filled by floats, my matrix is n x n+1, for testing is n=5, so it is matrix 5 x 6. What call of Scatter would be working and what approach should I take from the side of a other processes? I mean, how to get data, which are sent by scatter?

Comment: How is your array defined, and how are you calling Scatter?

Answer (score 9):

This is very similar to this question: [How to MPI_Gatherv columns from processor, where each process may send different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371733/how-to-mpi-gatherv-columns-from-processor-where-each-process-may-send-different/5373104#5373104) .  The issue is that columns aren't contiguous in memory, so you have to play around.

As is always the case in C, lacking real multidimensional arrays, you have to be a little careful about memory layout.   I *believe* in C it's the case that a statically-declared array like

```
float a[nrows][ncols]
```

will be contiguous in memory, so you should be alright for now.  However, be aware that as soon as you go to dynamic allocation, this will no longer be the case; you'd have to allocate all the data at once to make sure that you get contiguous data, eg

```
float **floatalloc2d(int n, int m) {
    float *data = (float *)malloc(n*m*sizeof(float));
    float **array = (float **)calloc(n*sizeof(float *));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        array[i] = &(data[i*m]);

    return array;
}

float floatfree2d(float **array) {
    free(array[0]);
    free(array);
    return;
}

/* ... */
float **a;
nrows = 3;
ncols = 2;
a = floatalloc2d(nrows,ncols);
```

but I think you're ok for now.

Now that you have your 2d array one way or another, you have to create your type.   The type you've described is fine if you are just sending one column; but the trick here is that if you're sending multiple columns, each column starts only one float past the start of the previous one, even though the column itself spans almost the whole array!  So you need to move the upper bound of the type for this to work:

```
       MPI_Datatype col, coltype;

       MPI_Type_vector(nrows,    
           1,                  
           ncols,         
           MPI_FLOAT,       
           &col);       

       MPI_Type_commit(&col);
       MPI_Type_create_resized(col, 0, 1*sizeof(float), &coltype);
       MPI_Type_commit(&coltype);
```

will do what you want.   NOTE that the *receiving* processes will have different types than the *sending* process, because they are storing a smaller number of columns; so the stride between elements is smaller.

Finally, you can now do your scatter,

```
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
if (rank == 0) {
    a = floatalloc2d(nrows,ncols);
    sendptr = &(a[0][0]);
} else {
    sendptr = NULL;
}
int ncolsperproc = ncols/size;  /* we're assuming this divides evenly */
b = floatalloc(nrows, ncolsperproc);

MPI_Datatype acol, acoltype, bcol, bcoltype;

if (rank == 0) {
    MPI_Type_vector(nrows,    
               1,                  
               ncols,         
               MPI_FLOAT,       
               &acol);       

     MPI_Type_commit(&acol);
     MPI_Type_create_resized(acol, 0, 1*sizeof(float), &acoltype);
}
MPI_Type_vector(nrows,    
               1,                  
               ncolsperproc,         
               MPI_FLOAT,       
               &bcol);       

MPI_Type_commit(&bcol);
MPI_Type_create_resized(bcol, 0, 1*sizeof(float), &bcoltype);
MPI_Type_commit(&bcoltype);

MPI_Scatter (sendptr, ncolsperproc, acoltype, &(b[0][0]), ncolsperproc, bcoltype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Thanks you for such a long reply! I will definitely try it. Meanwhile I was thinking about my whole problem. I am doing parallel Gaussian elimination. So at the start I wanted to send to all other processes columns for computing pivot. But now I am sending whole matrix to all of them, so I kind of a hope that whole matrix will be better... processes will be doing counting between rows, so I think it is useful to have matrix on all processes.

Answer (score 3):

There's quite a few things wrong with that, but your main problem is memory layout. At the memory location denoted by `a`, there isn't a single `float`: there are only `float*`s that point to various arrays of `float` elsewhere in memory. Since these arrays are not necessarily contiguous, you can't use [Scatter](http://www.netlib.org/utk/papers/mpi-book/node102.html#SECTION00570000000000000000) on them.

The easiest solution would be to store your matrix in a single array:

```
float a[100*101];
```

And fill it in column-major order. Then simply Scatter like so:

```
MPI_Scatter(a, 100*101, MPI_FLOAT, send, 10*101, MPI_FLOAT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This is assuming that you Scatter between 10 processes and `send` is defined as a `float[10*101]` in each process. Note that in the code you posted, arguments 4-6 of Scatter are definitely flawed. If `send` is an array, then you don't need to pass `&send` (for the same reason you don't need to pass `&a` in the first argument), and you want to match the number and type of data items you receive to what you send.

Comment: Thanks for comment, but I will do some computing with the colums, so having a[100*101] field is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Scatter tries to send the data it has to send in equal proportions. Unfortunately the data in C gets stored rowwise, not columnwise. Therefore your call would cause Scatter to take the n elements, and then send each process m = n/(number of processes) floats.

A common approach for this problem to create a new MPI-vector datatype (see the function MPI_Type_vector), in which you would be able to overcome the problem of the rowwise data storage of C arrays (because you can define the stride between to elements in the vector, which would exactly be the lenght of one line).

I haven't used scatter with a vector this way, so I am not sure whether this will help for the call of Scatter, but at least you are able to access the data columnwise easily. Then it would be an easy way to communicate this data to the corresponing processes by making use of a loop

Comment: Hi, see my edit2. I have made new MPI_type_vector, but now I am confused, how to pass right values to the scatter or even to Send... could you help me please?