# Sending columns of a matrix using MPI_Scatter

Tags: c, mpi

I'm trying to write a matrix-vector multiplication program using MPI. I'm trying to send columns of the matrix to separate processes and locally calculate the result. In the end I do a `MPI_Reduce` using `MPI_SUM` operation.

Sending rows of a matrix is easy as C stores arrays in row-major order, but columns is not (if you don't send them one by one). I read the question here:

[MPI_Scatter - sending columns of 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512245/mpi-scatter-sending-columns-of-2d-array)

Jonathan Dursi suggested using new MPI datatypes and here's what I've done by adapting his code to my own needs:

```
  double matrix[10][10];
  double mytype[10][10];
  int part_size; // stores how many cols a process needs to work on
  MPI_Datatype col, coltype;
  // ...
  MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, N, MPI_DOUBLE, &col);
  MPI_Type_commit(&col);
  MPI_Type_create_resized(col, 0, 1*sizeof(double), &coltype);
  MPI_Type_commit(&coltype);
  // ...
  MPI_Scatter(matrix, part_size, coltype,
              mypart, part_size, coltype,
              0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  // calculations...
  MPI_Reduce(local_result, global_result,
             N, MPI_DOUBLE,
             MPI_SUM,
             0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

This works perfectly, but I can't say I really understand how it works.

1. How is `MPI_Type_vector` stored in the memory?
2. How does `MPI_Type_create_resized()` work and what does it exactly do?

Please bear in mind that I'm a total beginner in MPI. Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for saying it's homework. :)

Comment: @hattenn Please do not use the [homework] tag any longer. It is deprecated. [see the tag itself to confirm this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There's a long description of this issue in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9271753/463827) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9269399/sending-blocks-of-2d-array-in-c-using-mpi/9271753#9271753):  the fact that many people have these questions is proof that it's not obvious and the ideas take some getting used to.

The important thing to know is what memory layout the MPI datatype describes.   The calling sequence to `MPI_Type_vector` is:

```
int MPI_Type_vector(int count,
                   int blocklength,
                   int stride, 
                   MPI_Datatype old_type,
                   MPI_Datatype *newtype_p)
```

It creates a new type which describes a layout of memory where every `stride` items, there is a block of `blocklength` items pulled out, and a total of `count` of these blocks.  Items here are in units of whatever the `old_type` was.  So for instance, if you called (naming the parameters here, which you can't actually do in C, but:)

```
 MPI_Type_vector(count=3, blocklength=2, stride=5, old_type=MPI_INT, &newtype);
```

Then `newtype` would describe a layout in memory like this:

```
   |<----->|  block length

   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   | X | X |   |   |   | X | X |   |   |   | X | X |   |   |   |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

   |<---- stride ----->|

   count = 3
```

where each square is one integer-sized chunk of memory, presumably 4 bytes.    Note that the stride is the distance in integers from the start of one block to the start of the next, not the distance between blocks.

Ok, so in your case you called

```
  MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, N, MPI_DOUBLE, &col);
```

which will take `count = N` blocks, each of size `blocklength=1` `MPI_DOUBLE`s, with a space between the start of each block of `stride=N` `MPI_DOUBLE`s.  In other words, it'll take every N'th double, a total of N times; perfect for extracting one column out of a (contiguously-stored) NxN array of doubles.    A handy check is to see how much data is being strided over (`count*stride = N*N` which is the full size of the matrix, check) and how much data is actually included (`count*blocksize = N`, which is the size of a column, check.)

If all you had to do was call MPI_Send and MPI_Recv to exchange individual columns, you'd be done; you could use this type to describe the layout of the column and you'd be fine.  But there's one more thing.

You want to call `MPI_Scatter`, which sends the first coltype (say) to processor 0, the next coltype to processor 1, etc.   If you're doing that with a simple 1d array, it's easy to figure out where the "next" data type is; if you're scattering 1 int to each processor, the "next" int starts immediately after the first int ends.

But your new coltype column has a total [extent](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-20-html/node77.htm) that goes from the start of the column to `N*N` `MPI_DOUBLE`s later -- if MPI_Scatter follows the same logic (it does), it would start looking for the "next" column outside of the matrices memory entirely, and so on with the next and next.  Not only would you not get the answer you wanted, the program would likely crash.

The way to fix this is to tell MPI that the "size" of this data type for the purposes of calculating where the "next" one lies is the size in memory between where one column starts and the next column starts; that is, exactly one `MPI_DOUBLE`.  This doesn't effect the amount of data sent, which is still 1 columns worth of data; it only affects the "next one in line" calculation.   With columns (or rows) in an array, you can just sent this size to be the appropriate step size in memory, and MPI will choose the correct next column to send.   Without this resize operator, your program would likely crash.

When you have more complicated data layouts, like in the 2d-blocks of a 2d-array example linked to above, then there is no one single step size between "next" items; you still need to do the resizing trick to make the size be some useful unit, but then you need to use [MPI_Scatterv](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Scatterv.html) rather than scatter to explicitly specify the locations to send from.

Comment: This is one of the clearest answers I've ever got on stackoverflow, thanks a lot. It's all clear now. I'd upvote 100 times if I could :)

Comment: Edinburgh Parallel Computing Centre provided us with an example of 2d scatter of a matrix which used the deprecated `MPI_Type_create_struct` with `MPI_UB` pseudo type to set the upper bound to be equal to the size of one matrix element (and they said that this was an awful hack). I wonder why they didn't use `MPI_Type_create_resized()` instead - it should have been implemented in Sun MPI circa 2003.

Comment: I think that sometimes people who give talks update their slides a lot less often than developers update their code; I know I've sometimes been guilty of using somewhat out-of-date examples well past their best-before date.

Comment: I mean the course was given in 2003. Hope that they've had it updated in the meantime. However, +1 for the clear explanation.