# Matrix Multiplication in MPI: Column-wise partitioning of second matrix

Tags: c, mpi, matrix-multiplication

I am working on a problem where I need to do matrix multiplication in MPI by slicing columns of one of the matrix to different processors.
A*B=C, B is to be sliced

I do the following:

`MPI_Bcast(A, n*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` where A is allocated to all ranks

```
MPI_Type_vector(n, n/p, n, MPI_DOUBLE, &tmp_type);
MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp_type, 0, n/p*sizeof(double), &col_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&col_type);

where n-size of A & B and p-no. of processors
```

`MPI_Scatter(B, 1, col_type, b, n/p*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` 
where B is allocated only on root and b is allocated on all ranks

`cblas_dgemm( CblasRowMajor,  CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, n, n/p, n, 1.0, A, n, b, n/p, 0.0, c, n/p );` 
where c allocated on all ranks
(Multiplication on each processor done by BLAS routine)

`MPI_Gather(c, n/p*n, MPI_DOUBLE, C, 1, col_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);` 
where C is allocated only on root

My code does do the required stuff for small matrices (sizes<62). But it fails for matrices bigger than this and gives the below error:

```
[csicluster01:12280] *** An error occurred in MPI_Gather
[csicluster01:12280] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[csicluster01:12280] *** MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated
[csicluster01:12280] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (your MPI job will now abort)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 12280 on
node csicluster01 exiting without calling "finalize". This may
have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Are there any obvious errors here that I have not been able to figure out?
Or is it possible that the problem might be because of some issue with the processors being used?

Comment: I guess you are either in the same class, or are the same person that already asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23974767/681865

Comment: well... he is my classmate but he couldn't specify the problem clearly, i think i have made the issue more clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending columns of a matrix using MPI\_Scatter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788180/sending-columns-of-a-matrix-using-mpi-scatter)

Comment: i've already gone through that post, its not a duplicate because here i mention a specific error that i get in some particular cases. this error has not been discussed anywhere. please answer by question if you have any clue as to what MPI may be doing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may come from

```
MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp_type, 0, n/p*sizeof(double), &col_type);
```

You may need to change it for

```
MPI_Type_create_resized(tmp_type, 0, n/p*n*sizeof(double), &col_type);
```

This change would seem logical since you perform things like

```
MPI_Scatter(B, 1, col_type, b, n/p*n, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

But i don't know if this change solves your issue of column partitionning. It might solve the issue of `MPI_Gather()` triggering error.

Bye,