# Unable to correctly receive custom MPI datatype

Tags: c, mpi, hpc

I'm trying to wrap my head around user created MPI datatypes so I have created a small demo program that I'm running on two nodes of a clusters.

This program is intended to have the first process create a matrix in stored inside a linear memory region in column order and then send multiple rows of that matrix to the second process by first creating an appropriate "matrix row" datatype. I know this is somewhat artificial, I just intended this to be a simple use case for `MPI_Type_vector`, don't worry about whether this should ordinarily done differently.

Now in this particular case, I'm trying to send the last to rows of the matrix constructed in the first process and receive/store them in the first two rows of the matrix allocated in the second process. However, this causes the receiving operation to fail with:

```
... free(): invalid pointer
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c619)[0x2b60c02e0619]
/sw/global/compilers/intel/2018/impi/2018.1.163/lib6/libmpi.so.12(+0x15ad6d)[0x2b60bee0fd6d]
/sw/global/compilers/intel/2018/impi/2018.1.163/lib64/libmpi.so.12(MPI_Recv+0x6b0)[0x2b60bf0e4020]
...
```

Here's the source code, I'm compiling with `icc 18.0.1` and running it on a (physical) Linux cluster. Is there some obvious mistake in my code?

```
#include <mpi.h>                                                                 
#include <stdio.h>                                                               
#include <stdlib.h>                                                              


int main()                                                                       
{                                                                                
    /* initialize MPI */                                                         
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);                                                        

    int world_size;                                                              
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);                                  

    int world_rank;                                                              
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);                                  

    /* create datatype */                                                        
    MPI_Datatype row_type;                                                       

    if (MPI_Type_vector(3, 1, 3, MPI_INT, &row_type) != MPI_SUCCESS)             
        return 1;                                                                

    if (MPI_Type_commit(&row_type) != MPI_SUCCESS)                               
        return 2;                                                                

    /* allocate dummy data */                                                    
    int *matrix = calloc(3 * 3, sizeof(int));                                    

    if (world_rank == 0) {                                                       
        int data = 1;                                                            
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c) {                                            
            for (int r = 0; r < 3; ++r)                                          
                matrix[c * 3 + r] = data++;                                      
        }                                                                        

        /* print ingoing data */                                                 
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 3; ++i)                                          
            printf("0: %d => %d\n", i, matrix[i]);                               

        if (MPI_Send(&matrix[1], 2, row_type, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) != MPI_SUCCESS)
            return 3;                                                            

    } else {                                                                     
        if (MPI_Recv(matrix, 2, row_type, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE) != MPI_SUCCESS)
            return 4;                                                            

        /* print received data */                                                
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 * 3; ++i)                                          
            printf("1: %d => %d\n", i, matrix[i]);                               
    }                                                                            

    /* clean up */                                                               
    free(matrix);                                                                

    MPI_Type_free(&row_type);                                                    

    MPI_Finalize();                                                              

    return 0;                                                                    
}
```

EDIT: this question seems to have the same solution as e.g. [Sending columns of a matrix using MPI_Scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788180/sending-columns-of-a-matrix-using-mpi-scatter). The accepted answer explains the problem well, it is trivial to see why this would cause my program to crash.

Comment: Valgrind might help you to figure out where that pointer was first allocated, if at all.

Comment: I am no expert, but doesn't MPI provide its own heap functions? Should you be using `calloc` to allocate data passed to an MPI function?

Comment: Unfortunately valgrind is not installed on the system I'm working with. I believe passing heap allocated data to MPI functions is unproblematic, that seems to be the usual way to do it.

Comment: Then you may need a time travelling debugger to break on that fault and then trace back to where that pointer came from. If I read the back-trace correctly, the free is happening in MPI_Recv.