# Unexpected distribution of columns when using using MPI_Scatter with MPI_Type_vector

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, scatter-matrix

I am trying to divide columns of a 2D matrix among N process with MPI. For template I used the example on [MPI_Scatter - sending columns of 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512245/mpi-scatter-sending-columns-of-2d-array).

My code:

```c
//HEADERS
    char** board_initialize(int n, int m)
    {
        int k, l;

        char* bd = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n * m);
        char** b = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            b[k] = &bd[k * m];

        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            for (l = 0; l < m; l++)
                b[k][l] = rand() < 0.25 * RAND_MAX;

        return b;
    }

    void board_print(char** b, int n, int m)
    {
        int k, l;

    //  system("@cls||clear");
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < m; l++)
                printf("%d", b[k][l]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

```c
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {   
        int N = 10;
        int i, j;

        char * boardptr = NULL;                 // ptr to board
        char ** board;                          // board, 2D matrix, contignous memory allocation!

        int procs, myid;            
        int mycols;
        char ** myboard;                        // part of board that belongs to a process

        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);                 // initiailzation
        
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);   // process ID
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs);  // number of processes

        // initialize global board
        if (myid == 0)
        {
            srand(1573949136);
            board = board_initialize(N, N);
            boardptr = *board;
            board_print(board, N, N);
        }
        // divide work
        mycols = N / procs;


        // initialize my structures
        myboard = board_initialize(N,mycols);

        MPI_Datatype column_not_resized, column_resized;
        MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, N, MPI_CHAR, &column_not_resized);
        MPI_Type_commit(&column_not_resized);
        MPI_Type_create_resized(column_not_resized, 0, 1*sizeof(char), &column_resized);
        MPI_Type_commit(&column_resized);

        // scatter initial matrix
        MPI_Scatter(boardptr, mycols, column_resized, *myboard, mycols, column_resized, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        board_print(myboard, N, mycols);
        
        MPI_Finalize();         // finalize MPI

        return 0;
    }
```

The whole board looks like:

```
0000010010
0100000000
0000101100
0101000010
1000000100
0000010010
0000001110
0110000100
0000100000
0100010010
```

And if I use 2 process I expect that each proces would get half (first process columns 1-5 and second proces columns 6-10). But if I print ***myboard*** of both process I get some strange results:

```
proc0:       proc1:
0 0 0 0 0    1 0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 0 0    0 0 0 1 1 
0 1 0 0 0    0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0    0 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1    0 1 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0    0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0    0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1    0 0 1 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0    0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0    0 1 0 0 0
```

It's probably some silly mistake, but I just can't seem to find it. Any help would be really appreciated. <3

*Note: the output of proc1 is probably just some garbage, because I get different output on every run.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to differentiate between send and receive types, i.e., the parameters of `MPI_Type_vector` will depend on the appropriate type. You need to do something as follows:

```
MPI_Datatype acol, acoltype, bcol, bcoltype;
if (myid == 0) {
    MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, N, MPI_CHAR, &acol);
    MPI_Type_commit(&acol);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(acol, 0, 1*sizeof(char), &acoltype);
}
MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, mycols, MPI_CHAR, &bcol);
MPI_Type_commit(&bcol);
MPI_Type_create_resized(bcol, 0, 1*sizeof(char), &bcoltype);
MPI_Type_commit(&bcoltype);
MPI_Scatter (boardptr, mycols, acoltype, *myboard, mycols, bcoltype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

From the sender point of view you want to create `N` blocks (*i.e.*, N rows), with a size of 1 and a stride of `N` (*i.e.,* N columns). Hence:

```
MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, N, MPI_CHAR, &acol);
```

From the receiver point of view you want to create `N` blocks (*i.e.*, N rows), with a size of 1 and a stride of `mycols`  (*i.e.,* mycols columns). Hence:

```
MPI_Type_vector(N, 1, mycols, MPI_CHAR, &bcol);
```

Side note you do need the MPI_Barrier after the MPI_Scatter since the latter is a blocking call already.

The final code would look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

    char** board_initialize(int n, int m)
    {
        int k, l;

        char* bd = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * n * m);
        char** b = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * n);
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            b[k] = &bd[k * m];

        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            for (l = 0; l < m; l++)
                b[k][l] = rand() < 0.25 * RAND_MAX;

        return b;
    }

    void board_print(char** b, int n, int m)
    {
        int k, l;

    //  system("@cls||clear");
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            for (l = 0; l < m; l++)
                printf("%d", b[k][l]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {   
        int N = 10;
        int i, j;

        char * boardptr = NULL;                 // ptr to board
        char ** board;                          // board, 2D matrix, contignous memory allocation!

        int procs, myid;            
        int mycols;
        char ** myboard;                        // part of board that belongs to a process

        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);                 // initiailzation
        
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);   // process ID
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &procs);  // number of processes

        // initialize global board
        if (myid == 0)
        {
            srand(1573949136);
            board = board_initialize(N, N);
            boardptr = *board;
            board_print(board, N, N);
        }
        // divide work
        mycols = N / procs;


        // initialize my structures
        myboard = board_initialize(N,mycols);
    MPI_Datatype acol, acoltype, bcol, bcoltype;

    if (myid == 0) {
            MPI_Type_vector(N,    
                1,                  
                N,         
                MPI_CHAR,       
                &acol);       
                MPI_Type_commit(&acol);
            MPI_Type_create_resized(acol, 0, 1*sizeof(char), &acoltype);
    }
    MPI_Type_vector(N,    
               1,                  
               mycols,         
               MPI_CHAR,       
               &bcol);       

    MPI_Type_commit(&bcol);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(bcol, 0, 1*sizeof(char), &bcoltype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&bcoltype);
    

    MPI_Scatter (boardptr, mycols, acoltype, *myboard, mycols, bcoltype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        board_print(myboard, N, mycols);
        
        MPI_Finalize();         // finalize MPI

        return 0;
    }
```

Alternatively, and much easier in IMO is to divide by rows instead of columns the code would look like the following:

```
int myrows = N / procs;
myboard = board_initialize(myrows, N);
MPI_Scatter (boardptr, myrows, MPI_CHAR, *myboard, myrows, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
board_print(myboard, myrows, N);
```