# How to MPI_Gather and MPI_Gatherv columns with MPI_Type_vector

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to send columns of a matrix from various processes to process 0 using MPI_Type_vector but I can't alternate the data correctly. My matrix is ​​saved in a one dimensional vector with concatenated rows. The example I wrote below assigns an equal number of columns to each process (so it uses MPI_Gather) and it doesn't work correctly, but my real goal is to be able to assign an arbitrary number of columns to the process with higher rank and use MPI_Gatherv, but I'm not even sure that it is possible to do it easily since the data of each process should alternate in a non-homogeneous way.

Considers that the result I would like to obtain with MPI_Gatherv is like the one of this question

[How to MPI_Gatherv columns from processor, where each process may send different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371733/how-to-mpi-gatherv-columns-from-processor-where-each-process-may-send-different)

but I use a 1-D vector.

The example I tried to write using MPI_Gather is as follows:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
  

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int worldRank;
    int WorldSize;
    MPI_Datatype column_send_type;
    MPI_Datatype column_send_type1;
    MPI_Datatype b_col_type;
    MPI_Datatype new_b_col_type;
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &worldRank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &WorldSize);
    vector <int> send (3*2);
    string stringRank = to_string(worldRank+1);
    for(int i=0; i < send.size(); i++) {
        send[i] = stoi(stringRank + to_string(i));
    }
    vector <int> rcv (3*8);
    MPI_Type_vector(3, 2, 2, MPI_INT, &column_send_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&column_send_type);

    MPI_Type_create_resized(column_send_type, 0, 6 *sizeof(int), &column_send_type1);
    MPI_Type_commit(&column_send_type1); 

    if (worldRank == 0)
    {
        MPI_Type_vector(3, 1, 8, MPI_INT, &b_col_type);
        MPI_Type_commit(&b_col_type);

        MPI_Type_create_resized(b_col_type, 0, 1*sizeof(int), &new_b_col_type);
        MPI_Type_commit(&new_b_col_type);
    }

    MPI_Gather(send.data(), 1, column_send_type1, rcv.data(), 2, new_b_col_type, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    if (worldRank == 0) {
        for(int i =0; i< rcv.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << rcv[i] << " ";
        }

    }
    

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**Update: inserted mpirun output**

Current output of `mpirun -np 4 testGatherCol2` is:
`10 13 20 23 30 33 40 43 11 14 21 24 31 34 41 44 12 15 22 25 32 35 42 45`

What I expect to get from this code is:
`10 11 20 21 30 31 40 41 12 13 22 23 32 33 42 43 14 15 24 25 34 35 44 45`

Comment: please always state your `mpirun` command line

Comment: a simpler strategy is to send **one** vector of 6 contiguous `MPI_INT`, and do the "positionning" in the receive datatype

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet please, could you give me a code example using this your strategy? Could it also be applied to the case where the higher ranked process sends more columns than the others?